# Delphi 2010 - CommandLink Button

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I decided to use a command link button on my form. Is there anyway i can change the color of the text (caption)? The Font property does not seem to change this. As you can see in this image

[image: Image of command link text],

the color is not very readable.

Comment: I don't see this color for either the font or the background. Perhaps you should add more details.

Comment: Use the background color that, e.g., add printer dialog uses, text will be readable.

Comment: It should be possible using VCL styles and the [vcl-style-utils](https://github.com/rruz/vcl-styles-utils).

Answer (score 2):

The command link button is a Windows common control and its font style and colors are controlled by the Windows system settings.
[Command Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I assume these buttons look the same for you in the windows system.
So the answer is: No, you cannot control the font color from within Delphi.